# Python Optunity: how to pass additional arguments to optimization routines

Tags: python, optimization, scikit-learn

### Background

I am using a support vector machine for binary classification on unbalanced classes (i.e. the ratio of positive to negative labels in my training set is ~100). I would like to optimize the following parameters: m (the ratio of positive to negative labels I sample from my training data), w (the class weight), and the SVM parameter C.

### Problem

I would like to optimize these parameters by doing a gridsearch, and have defined the score function as follows:

```
def svm_acc(X, y, m, w, c):
  X, y = balanceClasses(X, y, m)
  clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', C=c, class_weight = {1: w})
  scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X, y, 5)
  return( scores.mean() )
```

where X is the feature matrix, y are binary classification labels, and `svm_acc` returns the mean accuracy from 5-fold cross-validation. I have tried the following in optunity:

```
import optunity as opt
s = opt.solvers.GridSearch(mult=[1,10], w=[1,10], c=[1,10])
best_pars, _ = s.optimize(svm_acc, X=X, y=y)
```

but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: optimize() got an unexpected keyword argument 'X'
```

I gathered from the documentation that `optimize` does not take any additional keyword arguments (`X` and `y`). I have tried different variations of the above but have not been able to figure out how to pass additional parameters that should not be optimized to the routine.

As far as I can see, I cannot use scikit-learn's gridsearch because I want to optimize the `m` parameter, which is not 'intrinsic' to the estimator. Could anybody point me to a solution or to other python packages for doing gridsearch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few comments before answering the actual question:

1. When using an RBF kernel, you really have to tune `gamma` to get good results. Only tuning misclassification penalties (`C` and `weights`) is not sufficient.
2. The [main API functions](http://optunity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/optunity.html) are `optunity.maximize`, `optunity.minimize` and `optunity.optimize`, not the solver-specific methods you are using. Though both offer similar functionality, the API functions are probably easier to use.
3. For real tuning tasks, I strongly recommend to use the default particle swarm optimizer over grid search. You will get better results in far fewer function evaluations (= time).
4. It might be easier to use Optunity's cross-validation facilities instead of scikit-learn's. This is entirely optional, though. You can find more information about this [here](http://optunity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/cross_validation.html).
5. The hyperparameters `m` and `w` are somewhat redundant. You don't have to balance classes if you're going to optimize class weights. I would stop optimizing class balance (for which you're necessarily under -or oversampling = changing your data).

## The solution

The function you specify for `optimize` has to be the objective function, that means the only arguments to this function must be the hyperparameters you want to optimize. For more information on this, please refer to [Optunity's paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.1114). In your specific example, this means that the arguments should be `c`, `m` and `w`.

To fix `X` and `y`, you can use any of the standard Python approaches, such as `functools.partial` or closures. In my opinion, closures are the cleanest method:

```
def fix_data(X_fixed, y_fixed):
    def svm_acc(m, w, c):
        X, y = balanceClasses(X_fixed, y_fixed, m)
        clf = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', C=c, class_weight = {1: w})
        scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X, y, 5)
        return( scores.mean() )

    return svm_acc
```

The function, `fix_data` fixes a certain data set `X_fixed` and `y_fixed` and produces a function which only has the hyperparameters as arguments, as required. Then you can do something like this (assuming you've constructed the solver etc.):

```
svm_acc_with_fixed_data = fix_data(X, y)
best_pars, _ = s.optimize(svm_acc_with_fixed_data)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and the quick reply!